# How to accurately detect color using opencv python

Tags: python, opencv

I have been working on a python script which detects the most dominate color in the current frame of a webcam, and I have something that can do red, green, and blue ok but its inaccurate sometimes. Here is my code:

```
# importing required libraries
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time

# taking the input from webcam
vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# running while loop just to make sure that
# our program keep running untill we stop it
while True:

# capturing the current frame
_, frame = vid.read()

# displaying the current frame
cv2.imshow("frame", frame)

# setting values for base colors
b = frame[:, :, :1]
g = frame[:, :, 1:2]
r = frame[:, :, 2:]

# computing the mean
b_mean = np.mean(b)
g_mean = np.mean(g)
r_mean = np.mean(r)

print("RGB SET:")
print(r_mean)
print(g_mean)
print(b_mean)

# displaying the most dominate color
if (b_mean > g_mean and b_mean > r_mean):
    print("Blue")
if (g_mean > r_mean and g_mean > b_mean):
    print("Green")
else:
    print("Red")

time.sleep(0.5)
```

My question is, How do I make it more accurate, and is it possible to detect more colors like purple, orange, yellow, or brown? Thanks for any replies in advance :)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "more accurate"? What is the result of the problem and what did you expect to get instead?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I hold a blue box infront of the camera and it gives me green, also I want it to detect more colors as I stated in my question.

Comment: Do you understand why it gives you green and not blue?

Comment: You can define more colors by adding new conditions for the r, g, b values.

Comment: How about just looking at the most dominant (populous) color from a histogram. You can make the histogram for N bins, say N=8 and get the color of the bin with the most counts.

Comment: mkrieger1 thank you, that solves one problem and fmw42 thank you, that solves the other problem!